# Scenes aren't switching properly

Tags: c#, winforms, scene

so I've got two scenes in a Windows Forms Application, and they're supposed to switch. However, it's not working correctly. Here's the code for Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chat_Room {
    public partial class SceneOne : Form {
        public SceneOne() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void createRoomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Form2 scene = new Form2();
            scene.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I know, this is a small question, but I had had all the code for both in this one form, and then I decided to split it up into two, but then once I moved the code, it stopped switching (now it just closes the first one). And yes, the second form is Form2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [msdn - Form.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed

So, when you call `this.Close()`, `scene` is disposed too as it is "*created within the object*".

As per [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/da32f4a5-217b-4e61-818d-ed24ebfd39ab/formhide-not-working-c-windows-form?forum=winforms), maybe you should try something like this:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.Show();
```

Comment: How should I go about this then?

Comment: That didn't close the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use   `this.Close()` Because That Will disposed the form

Have a look at Form.Designer.cs

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

instead of use `this.Close()` Try hide the form `this.Hide`

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: Oh sorry I not pay attention to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The point is how you start your `Application`.

Just modify your Main method like this:

```
namespace Chat_Room 
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
//Need this, because if you do it in your Run method, appication will closes immediatly after you close the form.
            (new SceneOne()).Show(); 
            Application.Run(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In the closing event of your last scene, call the `Application.Ext()` method.

To know more, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) reference:

```
public static void Run(
    Form mainForm
)
```

*This method adds an event handler to the mainForm parameter for the Closed event. The event handler calls ExitThread to clean up the application.*

Also from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) If you are using

```
public static void Run()
```

*In Windows Forms, this loop is closed when the Exit method is called, or when the ExitThread method is called on the thread that is running the main message loop.*

So if you choose the `Application.Run()`(so without parameters), you have to call `Application.Exit` method to close the application.

So need to

Comment: How is this supposed to prevent `Close()` from disposing `scene` in `SceneOne`?

Comment: He doesn't states, that he'd like to prevent `Close()` from disposing scene.

Comment: He wants `scene` to show up. If `scene` gets disposed right after being created, how could it show up?